# Electron: How to dynamically create windows?

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to create any window with one function, and be able to identify it?

```
let newWindow;

function createNewWindow(window) {
        newWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 600, height: 400});
        newWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/windows/${window}.html`)
    }
}

createNewWindow("window1"); // Loads window1.html
createNewWindow("window2"); // Loads window2.html
```

The problem now is that both windows are created as `newWindow`, and calling `newWindow.focus()` for example, focuses the second window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are sharing the variable for both windows. After the second `createNewWindow('window2')` call your newWindow points to the second BrowserWindow. Try using different variables.

```
function createNewWindow(window) { 
        const newWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 600, height: 400});
        newWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/windows/${window}.html`)
        return newWindow;
    }
}

let secondWindow = createNewWindow("window2");
```